# Creating random keys for binary searching tree

Tags: binary-tree

My goal is to create a BST (Binary Search Tree) for compiler of pseudo-pascal code.

From what I know BST works like this: I have a root, which has some key - in dependency on MY GENERATED KEY (if it is greater or lesser than root key) I insert a node to the left or right from the root.

Obviously, if I use numbers for keys, the tree will go like:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
```

What I want is a balanced BST, something like this:

```
  1
 / \
2   3
... etc.
```

Which is obviously not gonna happen with those keys. How should keys for nodes look like when I want to achieve this structure? Is there a way to do this without remembering the last inserted key?

That also brings me to the question what "key" should be used for absolute root of the tree? So I can add keys to the left and to the right from it?

Comment: You've tagged this C, and binary-tree.  Do you have a C code example showing what you have tried?  ***[sscce](http://sscce.org/)***

Comment: I think 2nd example should be  `2` to the root.

Comment: @ryyker Yes, I did have the code for it, but it was not relevant to the question, since I was more curious about the principle of it. I edited the tags. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a node, you travel from root node down to find proper insertion point:

```
1     1     1
       \     \
        2     2
               \
                3
```

After insertion, when you return back to root, on the way you check that each left and right nodes are balanced enough. If not, you rotate them:

```
1         2
 \       / \
  2     1   3
   \
    3
```

This means that first node of deeper branch comes the new root node, and old root node will become child of this node.

So root node will change when necessary, and will always have the "most middle" value.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the concept of `AVL tree` to balance the tree structure.

According to your requirement:

```
    1
   / \
  2   3
```

The above tree is constructed just considering a `binary tree` not a `binary Search Tree`.

However above mentioned tree can be constructed by top-to-down and from left-to-right fashion.